Does `open --arch ARCH` working on the wrong processor mean an ARM emulator is present for Intel machines running macOS?
From man open:
 --arch ARCH
     Launch with the given cpu architecture type and subtype; ARCH should be one of
     any, arm, arm64, arm64e, arm64_32, x86_64, x86_64h, i386.  Two integers
     matching the values for cpu_type_t and cpu_subtype_t can be specified as
     integers separated by a '/' character, like "12/13" for
     CPU_TYPE_ARM/CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V8.

I have an intel MBP (2019) but open -a /Applications/Safari.app --arch arm64e launches a working Safari.  Is there an arm emulator bundled into 15.1.1 (24B91)?
Relted: cpu_type_t and cpu_subtype_t — definitions

No, the binary is fat (contains several build targets in an app wrapper) and the only code that can execute does. I would argue this is the correct behavior for open, but I suppose reasonable people could expect a strict interpretation and would rather get an error than an app that could open, not opening.

You can test this out empirically by specifying each architecture sequentially and running sudo sample PID 1 500|head -12 and verifying the Path, Identifier, Version and Code Type is native or (translated) where PID is the process ID of the app that you open.
On Apple silicon,  --arch i386 runs on native ARM, --arch x86_64 is translated Intel code.
Analysis of sampling Safari (pid 53256) every 500 milliseconds
Process:         Safari [53256]
Path:            /System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Load Address:    0x102800000
Identifier:      com.apple.Safari
Version:         18.1.1 (20619.2.8.11.12)
Build Info:      Safari-7619002008011012~2
Code Type:       ARM64E
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Analysis of sampling Safari (pid 53350) every 500 milliseconds
Process:         Safari [53350]
Path:            /System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Load Address:    0x1008ae000
Identifier:      com.apple.Safari
Version:         18.1.1 (20619.2.8.11.12)
Build Info:      Safari-7619002008011012~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (translated)
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  launchd [1]


i386 is the 32-bit Intel architecture, how does that run “natively” on Apple silicon?

The point is to show non-sensical requests choose the default code base, rather than throwing an error @MartinR as well as how to inspect the detail instead of just major architecture class in Activity monitor.

Yes, I am just confused by your statement that “On Apple silicon, --arch i386 runs natively.”

I misunderstood where I was confusing to you - my apologies and thanks for the comment. Does my edit make the intent more clear?

Sorry but I still don't get what that sentence is supposed to mean. i386 is the 32-bit Intel architecture. 32-bit Intel code does not run on ARM at all, neither natively nor translated via Rosetta.

Of course it doesn’t run. This is the same point as the OP asking to run ARM on intel. It’s not an appropriate instruction set even if you load an app. My point is you can’t just invoke things with open

That explains what happened.  But it makes no sense for a command to have options that cannot possibly do what the man page says they do.  That's why I triecd it, to see what would happen.  I did expect something like "You can't run an ARM app on this machine."  Or maybe "This MBP has no way to run an ARM executable; launching 386 executable instead."

I would consider —arch XXX to be implemented currently as optional - the open of the file or app will be attempted regardless of whether this modifier is possible (valid Rosetta 2 target, and Rosetta 2 installed) or makes any sense (i386 was dropped entirely a full release before Rosetta 2 came, zero support for that now with or without an Arm version of macOS being delivered with the Intel version @WGroleau
